# escaping html tags and reading only the text in php?

Tags: php, html, escaping

I was wondering is there a way to escape all html tags from a a bunch of html code, and extract only the text i.e.

```
<strong>this is strong</strong>
<br />
<h1> this is a header</h1>
```

and I want to get the text between the tags only, so basically only
`this is strong this is a header`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
```

One of the things I love about PHP...thoughtful functions for web developers.

Comment: whats fragements lol, thanks for a very clear answer :)) +upvote from me

Answer (score 2):

Use [strip_tags()](http://php.net/strip-tags) like this:

```
$html = "<strong>this is strong</strong><br />\n".
        "<h1> this is a header</h1>";
$text = strip_tags($html);
```

Answer (score 1):

use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function

```
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
```

will output

> Test paragraph. Other text

Answer (score 0):

To strip an entire block of HTML, http://www.phpro.org/examples/Get-Text-Between-Tags.html has some good functions and examples.